# SSH remote problems - ongoing issue: Besides ssh not running on the Linux host or firewall running on that host, what other issues could it be?

Tags: networking, macos, ssh, firewall, linux-mint

**Regarding the firewall:**

Linux Mint uses UFW by default. I disabled it with `sudo ufw disable`.

**Regarding the SSH Server service not running:**

I started it after I got a "Connection refused", leading me to believe that the SSH daemon was not running.

I opened up a terminal window on Mint and typed:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

That installed the SSH server for me. To make sure its running, I typed:

```
service ssh status
```

If I'm working over a LAN, would there not be a need to configure ports on the router? Wouldn't all ports be open to computers on a LAN by default?

To connect, I just tried...

```
ssh 10.0.0.188
```

The system did not ask me for user name and password (even though I believe that it shouldn't display anything at all when entering the password). Instead the following error appeared:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.188 port 22: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

What's `service sshd status` telling you?

Is the Mint system 10.0.0.188?

Check out `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on 10.0.0.188, ensure the `Port` line has a value of your desired port and use your preferred authentication method. Given the commands you've tried, it looks like you might want to test first with just passwords so ensure the `PasswordAuthentication yes' line is uncommented though use public keys once you can. After you made a change to`sshd_config`, restart the service.

Comment: The `service ssh status` is telling me `ssh start/running, process 844`. Yes, the Mint system is 10.0.0.188. When I enter `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, I get `bash: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied`

Comment: You need to be super user to read sshd_config